# How to retrieve lists of keys and values of a dictionary through a list comprehension?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension

This is a MWE that shows what I want to obtain but using a for loop:

```
a = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}
b = []
c = []
for key, value in a.items():
  b.append(key)
  c.append(value)

print(b) # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
print(c) # [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I want to obtain the same result in one line using list comprehension.
`b,c = [(key, value) for key, value in a.items()]` results in an unpack error because it assign to b and c, respectively, the first and second item of a and then it doesn't know where unpack the other items. `b,c = [key, value for key, value in a.items()]` results again in an error, a syntax one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
b, c = map(list, zip(*a.items()))
print(b)
print(c)
```

This outputs:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Is this the only solution or could it be implemented also through list comprehension?

Comment: You can also simply do: `b = list(a.keys())` and `c = list(a.values())`, but I really don't see any way to do it through list comprehension in a meaningful way.